# Replace values with #<value># with date - '01-Jan-2015'

Tags: text-processing

I want to replace values in file.

Replace :

- values `#startdate#` with - `'01-Jan-2015'`
- values `#code#`     with - `'SA','CA'`

Comment: what have you tried so far ? this seems pretty easy, try searchinf for `sed` tag.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace in a file named "filename" do

```
sed -i 's/#startdate#/01-Jan-2015/g' filename
```

the `-i` option will overwrite your file on linux

and

```
sed -i 's/#CODE#/"'CA','03'"/g' filename
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply.

I have the SQL syntax as '#StartEffStartDate#' and '#EndEffStartDate#'
I need this to be '01-Jan-2015' and '21-Jan-2015' after replace.                                                  

I can replace StartEffStartDate with 01-Jan-2015.

I need help to replace including #StartEffStartDate#

Comment: sed -i 's/#CODE#/'CA','03'/g' Test.sql

This gives ouput as "in (X,03);"

I want the output to be "in ('X','03');"

Comment: I updated my answer... But I'm not sure I understood your last comment